# Conditional Probability given Joint density Function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, descriptive-statistics

Let X and Y be continuous random variables with joint density function

$f(x,y)=24xy$ on the domain $x,y>0, 0<x+y<1$ and is $0$ otherwise

What is the conditional probability?

$$P(X>1/2 | X+Y<3/4)$$

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

I can find $P(X>1/2)$ and $P(X+Y<3/4)$ but I don’t know how find the conditional probability.

Answer is given as $\frac{1}{9}$. I have no idea how to get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The conditional probability would be calculated as follows (from the definition):

$$P(X>1/2 | X+Y < 3/4) = \frac{P(X>1/2 \cap X + Y <3/4)}{P(X+Y < 3/4)}$$

You’ve already solved for the denominator, so you need to formulate the correct double integral for the numerator :

$$\int_{1/2}^{3/4} \int_0^{3/4-x} 24xy\;dydx $$

Can you take from here?

Comment: No :c I'm not sure about the limits of integration

Comment: @RoseAhgase how did you find the other two probabilities you mentioned in your post?

Comment: Marginal density function of X for the first one and joint probability density function for the other one(I used these limits of integration 0<x<3/4 and 0<y<3/4-x)

Comment: @RoseAhgase I think you are close .. updated answer

Comment: Is that the integral for the numerator? Cuz I did it but I can't get 1/9 :c I got 1/8 as final result

Comment: I got it now. Thank u so much *heart*

Comment: @RoseAhgase if this helped then you can mark it as accepted